# Setting sensitivity of menu item associated with Gio.Action

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I created a menubar using the Python bindings for GTK3 and `Gio.Action` instead of `Gtk.Action`, similar to how it is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19607530/2748899).

But now I'm having trouble trying to dynamically set the *sensitivity* of a menu item (whether it is greyed out). `Gtk.Action` provides a simple `set_sensitive` method, but I can't find a clean way of getting the `Gtk.Action` associated with my `Gio.Action`. `Gtk.Application` only has methods for directly getting the `Gio.MenuModel`s, not the `Gtk.Menu`, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gio.SimpleAction.set_enabled()](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/SimpleAction.html#Gio.SimpleAction.set_enabled)

```
action = Gio.SimpleAction.new('my-action', None)
action.set_enabled(False) # This makes it insensitive
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I saw that method as well, but was put off by the remark "This should only be called by the implementor of the action. Users of the action should not attempt to modify its enabled flag." - Any comments on this?

Comment: They are saying don't go around disabling actions for other libraries since you technically can.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misread it, thinking that this was a method which was supposed to be private but isn't for some technical reason (i.e. I thought "implementor" = the GTK developers). It makes sense now, thanks!